# xamarinf.forms android Task.run() cause app to freeze when in background after few minutes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

My goal is to create a task that run **as long as the app is running**, no metter if the app in foreground / background or if the screen is turned off.

i have this simple code in xamarin.forms MainPage.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int _num = 0;
    Label l = new Label();
    Button b;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        l.TextColor = Color.Black;
        l.Text = "AAAA";
        b = new Button();
        b.Clicked += B_Clicked;

        StackLayout s = new StackLayout();
        s.Children.Add(l);
        s.Children.Add(b);

        Content = s;

        Task.Run(() => incNumberTaskWork());
    }

    private void B_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        l.Text = _num.ToString();
    }

    void incNumberTaskWork()
    {
        while (_num < 0xffffffff)
        {
            _num++;
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

The app freezes after ~10 minutes - tried it 3 times, when the app was in background + screen turned off after 5 minutes.

it worked well for the first few minutes

Checked it on android Samsung S7

what am i doing wrong ? is the same problem exists for IOS also ?

Comment: Please view the best practices for asynchronous process in this MSDN site [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). AND if you want to run background services, read through this article [link](http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/).

Comment: so the only way to run code in background if the screen is off is services ? isn't there a way to keep the app running if it's in background or screen is off ?

Comment: Other than services, that is more efficient and follow design patterns, no.

Answer (score -1):

In general, mobile apps can't run in the background (see Activities lifecycle https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). On iOS you can't even think about that expect in some strict cases which are allowed (like audio player). On Android it is a bit less strict and you can use Background service https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html.